# Delphi XE5 TBlobField.SaveToStream outputs only 4 bytes for a mysql blob field

Tags: mysql, image, delphi, blob

I'm inserting an image file into a blob field using...

```
procedure TfrmMain.FileToDB(filename: string; blobfield: TBlobField);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(filename,fmOpenRead);
  try
    BlobField.LoadFromStream(FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This works fine, and I can even open the file in mysql workbench and as it's an image file I can also view it.

When I try to save the image back to disk using...

```
procedure TfrmMain.DBToFile(filename: string; blobfield: TBlobField);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(filename,fmCreate);
  try
    BlobField.SaveToStream(FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I get a file of only 4 bytes. ??
I've tried this with BLOB / MEDIUMBLOB / LARGEBLOB type fields, and using the above BlobField.SaveToStream() method, as well as creating a blob stream and using FS.CopyFrom().  When using the later method, the blobstream.size property shows a value of 4 also.

I'm using the unicode driver, and a unicode schema in mysql. What could be going on here?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the BlobField's `SaveToFile` method?

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TBlobField.SaveToFile

Comment: Cannot reproduce this problem using Delphi XE and TADOxx components. The code that you show here does not expose the problem. Please add your table loading code.

Comment: Or even better, please provide a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Actually, I should have mentioned that I was using FireDAC. I switched out the FireDAC connection and table for the ADO equivalents and everything started working (no other changes). I suspect a bug in FireDAC.

Comment: Ok, waisted my time here then. Next time try to add all the details. Details matter you know ;)

Comment: What Delphi version ([add a tag](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21760432/edit))? Quite important with FireDac being new to the latest Delphi XEx versions

Answer (score 0):

While the problem is not resolved using FireDAC, switching to ADO components got me past this issue.

Comment: I suggest you make that a reproducible case and shoot it into [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx). And while you're at it, [update your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21760432/edit) with the reproducible case code.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TfrmMain.DBToFile(filename: string; blobfield: TBlobField);
var
  FS: TFileStream;   
begin
 FS := TFileStream.Create(filename,fmCreate);
 try
    BlobField.SaveToStream(FS);
    **FS.position:=0; // It can help**
 finally
   FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```